# Using tree Command in C++ on C://

Tags: c++, windows, tree, cmd, cd

I want to use the Windows CMD tree command in my C++ console application. My code:

```
system("cd c:/");
system("tree");
```

The problem is that the command tree will execute on the folder path where the program is running and not on C://. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Many tasks that require this kind of ability tend not to be suited to C++, but more to something "scripty".  If your task really warrants programming in C++, you might find it worth checking into `boost.filesystem` where you'll get into stuff like [`boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233640/boostfilesystemrecursive-directory-iterator-with-filter).  If you wind up thinking that's heavy-handed, and you'd rather just be processing stdout spew, you might be better off with an interpreted language of your choice.  *(or heck, batch files, even)*

Comment: Also, Visual Studio 2013 ships with test implementation of [TR2 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1975.html) of [`std::filesystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SetCurrentDirectory from windows.h. This page has a demonstration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not :

```
system("tree c:\");
```

?

```
TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `system("cd c:/")` is executed in a shell, and then the shell exits. [It's also wrong, because you use the wrong kind of slash, it should be `"cd c:\\"` - the double backslash is needed to make one backslash in the output, assuming we're talking about a Windows system].

There are a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Use `chdir()` (or `SetCurrentDirectory`) function call to change the main processes current working directory, and then call `system("...")`. This is the simplest solution.
2. Generate all your commands into a batch file, then pass the batch file to `system`.
3. Open a command shell with something like `_popen()` and pass commands into the pipe that you get from that.
4. Manually create pipes and connect them to the standard in and standard out of a process that runs the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just for programs in Windows, include "windows.h", then

```
SetCurrentDirectory("c:/");
system("pwd");
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still curious why would you want to do this, you can try to run all commands in one `system()` call:

```
system("cd c: && c: && tree");
```

Second `c:` is needed to change drive letter, in case if you're not currently on drive `c:` (because `cd` doesn't do it).