# Recursive count_files function not returning complete results

Tags: c++, c, function, recursion

I am writing a recursive function in C/C++ for counting all files and directories within a given file path and it's subdirectories. The function has two parameters- the search directory and the file_count int, set by default to a value of 0.

```
int count_files(char * directory, int file_count = 0) {
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * entry;
    dirp = opendir(directory);
    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { 
            file_count++;
        } else if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            if(strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            } else {
                file_count++;
                char rcsvdir[256];
                sprintf(rcsvdir, "%s%s/", directory, entry->d_name);
                count_files(rcsvdir, file_count);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    return file_count;
}
```

The trouble I'm having is that it doesn't count all files in subdirectories. Imagine a directory with subdirectories like this:

```
-root
    file1
    file2
    file3
    -sub1
        file1
        file2
    -sub2
        file1
        file2
```

The expected return integer would be **9** (2 dirs, 7 files), though it returns **5**. To my understanding, it is **counting all files in the root directory, but only the first file in the subdirectories**. Any help as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update

The issue was resolved by replacing this line:

```
count_files(rcsvdir, file_count);
```

with the following:

```
file_count = count_files(rcsvdir, file_count);
```

Thanks to @IInspectable

Comment: Did you mean to say `sprintf(rcsvdir, "%s/%s", directory, entry->d_name);`?

Comment: Have you used a debugger and/or debug print statements to debug the problem?

Comment: @SteveSummit I was using `./root/` as the input, so it would become `./root/sub1/` for example

Comment: @kaylum I placed some printfs throughout the function to ouput the current count, and it appeared to have only counted one file in each of the sub dirs.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `count_files`. You probably need `file_count=count_files(rcsvdir, file_count)` in your recursive call. And some protection against infinite recursion due to soft links/junction points.

Comment: @IInspectable You were completely correct; that was the problem. I'm receiving correct ouput now. Thanks!

Comment: How about to use boost::filesystem?  for instance look at the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233640/boostfilesystemrecursive-directory-iterator-with-filter

Comment: @user1877600 I was looking for a solution without having to use an external library, though that is one of way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ignore the return value of the recursive function, you likely need:

```
char rcsvdir[256];
sprintf(rcsvdir, "%s%s/", directory, entry->d_name);
file_count += count_files(rcsvdir, file_count);
```

Instead of:

```
file_count++;
....    
count_files(rcsvdir, file_count);
```

This way instead of forgetting the amount of files returned by the function and only incrementing by 1, you are incrementing the number of files found in the subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This ended up to be the anwser

Comment: The explanation is wrong. By ignoring the return value of the **recursive** call you aren't counting subdirectories. Only files/directories of the initial directory are counted.