# is C++17 std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::pop equal to boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::no_push

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

As the C++17 `std::filesystem` is very similar to the `boost::filesystem`, I was trying to do the same thing asked in this question: [Escaping some Directories in iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233640/boostfilesystemrecursive-directory-iterator-with-filter)

But I found out that in the `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` there is no `no_push` method implemented, and the nearest match to it is the `pop` method, but are they exactly equal in functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `no_push()` or `no_push(true)` is `disable_recursion_pending()`.

There's no equivalent of `no_push(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

They are not at all the same. [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::pop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/pop)

> Moves the iterator one level up in the directory hierarchy.

Where as [boost::filesystem::recursive_directory::no_push](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator)

> Prevents the next iteration on a directory from moving into that directory.

`no_push` does not change the current iterator where as `pop` moves the iterator up. Boost also has a `pop` method that is the same as the standard.

The Standard has options, without them it will not iterate a symlink folder, where as you would use `no_posh` with boost to avoid iterating into a symlink folder.